# How to keep C program running

Tags: c, loops

Hey my program is an RFID reader, a user scans his rfid tag, the rfid tag value is checked in the database, if the value corresponds with the rfid tag database value the door opens and 2 queries are inserted. How do i keep it running? I can only scan one tag, then i need to close the program only then the check will be done including the 2 queries. How can everything be done simultaneously(all code thats in my main)? Do i use a while loop? Thanks

```
//gcc -o RFID $(mysql_config --cflags) RFID.c $(mysql_config --libs) -std=gnu99 -lphidget21
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <phidget21.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

char tagVal1[10];


int CCONV TagHandler(CPhidgetRFIDHandle RFID, void *usrptr, char *TagVal, CPhidgetRFID_Protocol proto) //Tag wordt gelezen en LED gaat aan
{ 
    CPhidgetRFID_setLEDOn(RFID, 1);


    printf("Tag Read: %s\n", TagVal);
    sprintf(tagVal1, "%s", TagVal);
}

int CCONV TagLostHandler(CPhidgetRFIDHandle RFID, void *usrptr, char *TagVal, CPhidgetRFID_Protocol proto) //Tag is verwijderd van RFID lezer
{
    CPhidgetRFID_setLEDOn(RFID, 0);

    printf("Tag Lost: %s\n", TagVal);
    return 0;
}



int rfid_simple()
{
    int result;
    const char *err;

    //Declare an RFID handle
    CPhidgetRFIDHandle rfid = 0;

    //RFID object wordt aangemaakt
    CPhidgetRFID_create(&rfid);

    //Wanneer de tag gelezen wordt, wordt het uitgeprint
    CPhidgetRFID_set_OnTag2_Handler(rfid, TagHandler, NULL);

    //Wanneer de tag  verwijderd wordt, wordt het uitgeprint
    CPhidgetRFID_set_OnTagLost2_Handler(rfid, TagLostHandler, NULL);

    //RFID wordt geopend voor connectie
    CPhidget_open((CPhidgetHandle)rfid, -1);

    //Programma wacht totdat RFID is aangesloten
    printf("Waiting for RFID to be attached....\n");
    if((result = CPhidget_waitForAttachment((CPhidgetHandle)rfid, 10000)))
    {
        CPhidget_getErrorDescription(result, &err);
        printf("Problem waiting for attachment: %s\n", err);
        return 0;
    }


    CPhidgetRFID_setAntennaOn(rfid, 1);

    //read RFID event data
    printf("RFID reader is aangesloten! Druk op enter om het programma af te sluiten\n");

    //keep displaying RFID event data until user input is read
    printf("RFID tag nodig\n");
    getchar();


    //RFID wordt afgesloten zodra er op Enter wordt gedrukt
    printf("Ik ga afsluiten vriend...\n");
    CPhidget_close((CPhidgetHandle)rfid);
    CPhidget_delete((CPhidgetHandle)rfid);
    return 0;
}
void finish_with_error(MYSQL *conn)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn)); //foutmelding voor mmysql connectie
  mysql_close(conn);
  exit(1);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

MYSQL *conn; rfid_simple(); 

    char* jeMoeder;
    jeMoeder = malloc(150);
    char* jeVader = "Open Deur";
    char *employeeID[20];

    //constants met verbindingsinfo
    const char *server = "" ;
    const char *user = "";
    const char *password =  "";
    const char *database = "";

    //verbinding met de database aanmaken
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }


     if (mysql_query(conn, "SELECT (Employee_id) FROM Employee")){finish_with_error(conn);} // gewoon een select query

  MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(conn);// opgehaalde data  in results storen

  if (result == NULL){finish_with_error(conn);}

    //We get the result set using the mysql_store_result() function. The MYSQL_RES is a structure for holding a result set.
    //geen zin om dit te vertalen naar NL

  int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result); // We get the number of fields (columns) in the table.
  const char* rfidTags[num_fields]; // string array declararen

    //We fetch the rows and print them to the screen. en slaat het op in string array

  MYSQL_ROW row;

  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
  {
      for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
      {
          printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
                  rfidTags[i] = row[i];//opslaan in rf[idtag arrays
        if(strcmp(rfidTags[i], tagVal1 ) == 0){
        printf("Tags zijn gelijk, open de deur.");



    //datestamp formuleren voor de sql database
    //bufbaf is de tijdelijke bufferstring voor het opbouwen van de timestamp
    time_t timer;
    char bufbaf[50];
    struct tm* tm_info;

    time(&timer);
    tm_info = localtime(&timer);

    //strftime: print de tijd als een string
    strftime(bufbaf, 30, "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", tm_info);
    puts(bufbaf);

    const char* insert = "INSERT INTO Notifications (Notification_id, Notification, Timestamp_Notification) VALUES (NULL, '";
    const char* insert2 = "'";
    const char* insert3 = ",'";
    const char* insert4 = argv[1];
    const char* insert5 = "')";

    char* statementOne;
    statementOne = malloc(strlen(insert) + 1 + 300);

    strcpy(statementOne, insert);
    strcat(statementOne, jeVader);
    strcat(statementOne, insert2);
    strcat(statementOne, insert3);
    strcat(statementOne, bufbaf);
    strcat(statementOne, insert5);

    printf("%s", statementOne, "\n");
    {mysql_error(conn);}
    printf("%s", mysql_error(conn));
    if (mysql_query(conn, ((char*) statementOne)) !=0){
        mysql_error(conn);
    }

    int lastid = mysql_insert_id(conn);
    printf("%d\n", lastid);
    sprintf(jeMoeder, "%ld", lastid);

    const char* insert6 = "INSERT INTO Access(Employee_id, Notification_id) VALUES('";
    const char* insert7 = "',";
    const char* insert8 = ")";

    //nieuwe char array aanmaken voor de uiteindelijke insert command
    char* statementTwo;
    //memory allocaten voor de totale string... ja c is raar en ouderwets
    statementTwo = malloc(strlen(insert6) + 1 + 150);
    //strcpy: string copy, strcat: string concatenate
    strcpy(statementTwo, insert6);
    strcat(statementTwo, tagVal1);
    strcat(statementTwo, insert7);
    strcat(statementTwo, jeMoeder);
    strcat(statementTwo, insert8);

    printf("%s", statementTwo, "\n"); //debugfunctie, print de geformuleerde statement naar de commandline
    //de query: conn is de verbinding met server, statement is de geprepareerde char array met de insert statement
    if (mysql_query(conn, ((char*) statementTwo)) !=0){
        mysql_error(conn);
    }
    mysql_close(conn);

    //printf("%s\n",tagVal1);
    return 0;
        }else{
        printf("Tags zijn onjuist, geen toegang tot de deur");
        }
      }
          printf("\n");

    //for(int a = 0; a < num_fields; a++){
     //printf("%s", rfidTags[a],"\n");}// testen van array: rfidtags
  }
  mysql_free_result(result);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code should be organized as a number of functions that main() calls for the setup of the database connect and queries etc. Then it would be easier to wrap only the RFID read and processing steps into a loop.

Comment: @Chimera How woud i exactly do that? I created a new function, put a while loop in it and called main();

Answer (score 1):

Although haphazard, you could just throw the whole thing into a "while" loop that goes forever and then just trap the KILL signal.  There's some examples [kill signal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287167/kill-signal-example) That will get you started.

A better format for your code would to be an initialization, a run procedure and then a cleanup.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I put a while(1) in my main, if i put it infront of MYSQL *conn i get an error saying that conn is undeclared. If i put it after MYSQL *conn, only the rfid_simple(); gets looped, not the MYSQL connection. How do i fix this?

Comment: You need to change where you have the while(1).  Move it down to be after you open the MYSQL connection and end it before you close it.  That way the connection stays open.   Fundamentally, an architectural change would serve you the best.  I know it's more work, but that's how it always goes.